# Multiple Identical Web Requests

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make multiple identical requests to a REST web service. The issue I am having is that for each request it seems like a new socket is opened which makes the operation *much* slower (~x10). (when compared to the same operation using a SOAP proxy channel).

I have looked into HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive, but I can't call GetResponse() on the same web request multiple times.

This snippet below is the idea of what I need, and yes I know it will not work because of the reasons I mentioned above:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUri);
req.KeepAlive = true;

var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));

while (enabled)
{
    var stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();                

    if (stream != null)
    {
        var test = (Test)dcs.ReadObject(stream);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the loop I am using for the SOAP test:

```
private void SoapLoop()
{
    IService1 proxy =
        ChannelFactory<IService1>.CreateChannel(
            tcpBinding, endpointAddress);



     while (enabled)
     {
         var test = proxy.GetRead(new GetReadRequest());
         counter++;
     }

}
```

The object I am transfering is the same in both SOAP and REST, and is ~300KB.

EDIT2: I did some further tests:

on small objects, e.g.: 100 bytes REST outperforms SOAP (~2 to 1), but on large objects (objects with large image byte arrays) SOAP is much faster.

Another odd thing is that when I comment out the line `var test = (Test)dcs.ReadObject(stream);` in the REST loop, the performance actually goes down :S.

Comment: Please don't append " C#" and such to the ends of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use different `WebRequests` and they will try to reuse the same connection. Are you sure that doesn't actually happen and that the server does support `Keep-Alive`?

Comment: Wrap your `GetResponse`and `GetResponseStream` into `using () { ... }` blocks because they implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

Close the first response before you open the new one. Please consider to put `GetXYZ()` inside a `using` statement. `KeepAlive` is `true` by default.

Comment: As I said above: This is Skeleton, it is Not meant as working code. I added stream.Close() and Response.Close(). The performance is better but still much slower than a similar loop that uses a SOAP based service.

Comment: So, if I understand, now above code works but performance aren't what you expect? Can you post the full code you use to test performances in both cases?